# Symfony cant load class in AppKerner

Tags: php, symfony

I have created new bundle class in src/UserBundle/UserBundle.php

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to load it in AppKerner.php

```
 $bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    new AppBundle\UserBundle(),
);
```

Getting next error - Attempted to load class "UserBundle" from namespace "AppBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

How it should be loaded?

Comment: Could you provide your complete `AppKernel.php`? Also, if possible only minimal code required to produce error (drop all the lines that doesn't cause the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your bundle is related to your namespace. The right namespace should be:

```
namespace AppBundle\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

And then you would load it as:

```
$bundles = array(
    new AppBundle\UserBundle\UserBundle()
);
```

The same applies for your `AppBundle` bundle. BTW you probably should rename the `src/AppBundle` to `src/App` to avoid using the "bundle" word.